# php -results should come in same page

Tags: php, javascript

I have written a login form, in this I have used, form and method is post and action is(PHP self) `<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>` (am using php in the form itself). In php i have written if the login is success then 'welcome' and if it fails then 'sorry'.

But those results are coming in a new page. I want to get those results in the same page when i click the submit button. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] for the action?

Comment: '$sql = "INSERT INTO emp ".
       "(empid,empname, salary) ".
       "VALUES('$emp_number','$emp_name',$emp_salary)";
mysql_select_db('emp');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">'

Comment: Sir above is the code..and working is fine..but those messages(successful or error messages should come in same page, without going to new page)

Comment: you need some sort of ajax call to show it in the same page...

Comment: @user1160126 Please post code in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language, so after submitting the login data, a new page is generated by the server, if you want the `welcome || sorry` message to be returned without refreshing the page, you'll need to use ajax. I gather you're rather new to all this, so google some javascript Tuts on ajax, or use a JavaScript lib if you need to have this up and running fast. The easiest imho is jQuery, as it is the most documented of the lot